# Weird <DIV> Behavior

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to create a view where I have one div broken into two columns that then displays a set of < label and value > together.  Underneath that two column layout, there should be a dividing line, and then a single column that spans the width of both above columns and displays a set of < label and value >.  So the finished product would have two columns above, then a dividing line, then one single column below that spans the width of both top columns.

For some reason, when I render this, the line (which i'm rendering with the border-bottom CSS property) is rendering at the very top of everything, and while I can get the two columns to display correctly, the single column is not rendering below the two column layout but rather looks like its just continuing the flow from the top layout.  So instead of this:

```
 label: value              label: value
 label: value              label: value
 label: value              label: value
 label: value              

      -----------------------------
 label: value value value value value value
 label: value value value value value value
```

I get this:

```
      -----------------------------
 label: value              label: value
 label: value              label: value
 label: value              label: value
 label: value              label: value value value value value value
 label: value value value value value value
```

Below is my HTML and CSS

**HTML**

```
 <div class="two-column-layout">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="field-set">
          <span class="label">From:</span>
              <span class="data">John Smith</span>
        </div>

        <div class="field-set">
          <span class="label">To:</span>
              <span class="data">Jane Smith</span>
        </div>

        <div class="field-set">
          <span class="label">Date Sent:</span>
          <span class="data">01 May 1916</span>
        </div>

        <div class="field-set">
          <span class="label">Sent From:</span>
              <span class="data">Dublin Castle</span>
        </div>

        <div class="field-set">
          <span class="label">Sent To:</span>
            <span class="data">St. Patricks College</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="field-set">
          <span class="label">Author&#39;s Gender:</span>
            <span class="data">Male</span>
        </div>

        <div class="field-set">
          <span class="label">Category:</span>
            <span class="data">Family Life,</span>
            <span class="data">Children,</span>
            <span class="data">Love Letters</span>
        </div>

        <div class="field-set">
          <span class="label">Institution:</span>
          <a class="data" target="_blank" href="http://www.nationalarchives.ie/visit-us/contact-us/">National Archives</a>
        </div>

        <div class="field-set">
          <span class="label">Collection:</span>
          <span class="data">Governor Letters</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br/>
<div class="single-column-layout">
  <div class="field-set">
    <span class="label">Subject:</span>
    <span class="data">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
  </div>

  <div class="field-set">
    <span class="label">Description:</span>
    <span class="data">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eu aliquet mauris. Cras nec ipsum et nisi iaculis placerat. Morbi massa libero, tempor quis sapien ut, pellentesque laoreet quam. Curabitur euismod mauris nec magna pharetra elementum.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.two-column-layout {
  max-width: 900px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.column {
    width: 48%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
  }

.single-column-layout {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.field-set {
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}

.fieldset .label {
    font-weight: bold;
  }

.fieldset .data {
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you could put a `clear: both` on your `<br>`. Since the ONLY content of your main parent `two-column-layout` div is two floated divs, that parent div is basicaly collapsing down to nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're floating the children in the two column div you need to set the overflow to auto to restore the behavior you seek, otherwise the parent will collapse and act like it has no content:

```
.two-column-layout {
    max-width: 900px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4qnvLjvz/)**

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks that worked! I knew it was something simple.